# Solution to Azure: New-AzCdnProfile: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-az-module

I am using Pay-as-you-go subscription and i was using below Powershell command to create cdn profile.

```
 New-AzCdnProfile -ProfileName "cdnprofileforcache" -ResourceGroupName "rg-cdn" -Sku "Premium_Verizon" -Location "Uk South" -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
```

it returns me with very minimal information as error.

> ```
> New-AzCdnProfile : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
> At line:1 char:1
> + New-AzCdnProfile -ProfileName "cdnprofileforcache" -ResourceGroupName "rg-cdn" ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzCdnProfile], ErrorResponseException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Cdn.Profile.NewAzureRmCdnProfile
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i try multiple option with Powershell i was trying to execute same command with Azure CLI and i got bellow error. Which makes more scenes to me.

> az : ERROR: (LocationNotAvailableForResourceType) The provided location 'uksouth' is not available for resource type 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles'. List of available regions for the resource type is 'global,australiaeast,australiasouth
> east,brazilsouth,canadacentral,canadaeast,centralindia,centralus,eastasia,eastus,eastus2,japaneast,japanwest,northcentralus,northeurope,southcentralus,southindia,southeastasia,westeurope,westindia,westus,westcentralus'.
> At line:1 char:1

- az cdn profile create --name cdnprofiledelHub --resource-group "HUB"  ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: (Locatio...westcentralus'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
  ```

Then i try this Powershell command

**Solutions :-**

```
New-AzCdnProfile -ProfileName "cdnprofileforcache" -ResourceGroupName "rg-cdn" -Sku "Premium_Verizon" -Location Global -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
```

**Conclusion**
You need to use only those region where 'Microsoft.Cdn' provider does support. As of now (12/10/2021) Microsoft does support for only below regions. The below regions or location will change.

1. global,
2. australiaeast,
3. australiasouth east,
4. brazilsouth,
5. canadacentral,
6. canadaeast,
7. centralindia,
8. centralus,
9. eastasia,
10. eastus,
11. eastus2,
12. japaneast,
13. japanwest,
14. northcentralus,
15. northeurope,
16. southcentralus,
17. southindia,
18. southeastasia,
19. westeurope,
20. westindia,
21. westus,
22. westcentralus